# Hi, i've been trying to refresh my table view in Xcode 7 and for some reason it is just not working?

Tags: xcode7

strong textSo what i have is a tableView on 'ViewController' and when the user moves to 'TimeTableCreater' they can input a value which will be able to change the number of rows in the table. however it is not refreshing the table. Also this all happens on the a button press. here is my code ViewController().tableView.reloadData()

Answer (score 0):

Assuming TimeTableCreater is a different ViewController and the code for adding values to your table is correct (please add this next time), move the tableView.reloadData() into the ViewDidAppear in the "ViewController"